# "Couldn't load private key (not a private key)" when converting id_rsa.pub to ppk using PuTTYgen

Tags: windows, putty, private-key, git-bash

I'm installing Git 2.5.0 (included with latest docker-toolbox) on my Windows 7 64-bit.

I try to regenerate new key using `git-bash`:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

and save the new key to specific location. When trying to convert using PuTTYgen to `.ppk` file there's error:

> Couldn't load private key (not a private key)

Is there something wrong with my Git version?

Here's the `.pub` file:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC4YN/jejgFKubJ7YBUdl18EKuxFcC2CS/Rl19u6giHIz6zP548guM22Vm1edOLHN6qh2tpJkbzN6FOtLrCUXQqQ4unBqPlAY0dU4Cvzh86TDqdWixOV3AuBGJAMmjrrGe/U3/yO1RgR1pARrl7ZpY7ma7tP/9o8rGDmbQclIULNcI5AYCjRLICgbDlawT8jRYBT33VztphLi9HzGgDtSPANGJpgRrnYcoF3ZJL4E/CC7SW33lz2S/cLsupDdjusPWJjzR8vDKCXYtBTjvNP+a5GY21Z7eQHwD0MBFdxyHCMM0rnVWMJFmNNYy0N2ho5TrJ7kUHbzz4tUfrGPdWzOqX dxx@dxx-SandBox
```

Comment: Show us the first line of the file you are trying to load to PuTTYgen.

Comment: i already show it ... the pub file (ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1y......), that's the first line of pub file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are obviously loading a public key to the PuTTYgen, not the private key.

---

The `ssh-keygen -t rsa` generates two files:

- The key pair `id_rsa` (containing both the public key and the private key):

  ```
  -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
  ...
  -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
  ```
- The public key `id_rsa.pub`:

  ```
  ssh-rsa ... comment
  ```

You cannot load the `id_rsa.pub` to PuTTYgen. It makes no sense, as the file does not contain the private key.

You have to load the `id_rsa`.

Comment: you've got the point, when i try id_rsa file it's works ... strange, usually i always use pub file to convert into ppk file

Comment: I was facing the similar problem but with different,  [Question-link](https://superuser.com/questions/1300574/puttygen-couldnt-load-private-keyunable-to-open-file)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  For Puttygen 6.2 the error was "Couldn't load private key (not a private key)" and for Puttygen 7 the error was "Couldn't load private key (not a recognised key file format)".

It turns out the solution was pretty simple - the .pem file I was using was saved with UNIX line endings (LF).  Converting the file to Windows line endings (CR LF) meant that Puttygen was able to read it.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what was the exact problem, but installing a new version of PuttyGen solved it.